# Вывод в поток массива вектора пар

Tags: c++, vector

```
int main()
{
    int gg;

    typedef std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> VectorPairIntInt;
    typedef std::pair<int, int> PairIntToInt;

    PairIntToInt p;
    VectorPairIntInt vCt[100];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        gg = rand() % 100;
        vCt[i].push_back(std::make_pair(i, gg));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        std::cout << &vCt[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

При попытке вывода в консоль выводит только адрес в памяти:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    std::cout << &vCt[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Как правильно вывести в поток `first` и `second` каждой пары из массива вектора?

Comment: Обязательно использовать вектор? С std::map проще получится.

Comment: Да, именно вектор нужен.

Comment: У вас в каждом векторе только одна пара. Так и задумано?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я не  обратил на это внимание. Автор вопроса просто сам ошибся, уверен, что  в его намерениях не было сделать его массивом векторов, во всяком случаи код  на это указывает...

Comment: typedef std::pair<int, int> PairIntToInt; и   PairIntToInt p;  лишняя писанина и захват памяти:  неиспользуете вы обьект p

Comment: Ваш код в текущем виде не компилируется. `push_back` должен вызываться для вектора, а не для элемента вектора, который является парой и возвращается после применения оператора `[]`.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Пожалуйста, не вносите в вопрос изменения, которые делают некорректными существующие ответы. По крайней мере, пока автор с этим не согласится.

Comment: @alexolut Изначально `vCt` выглядел как `VectorPairIntInt vCt[100];`, и все работало. Правка, сделанная AR Hovsepyan, убирает `[100]`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я не изменял просто, а поправлял ошибку, чтобы код соответствовал обьявлению:

Comment: @ARHovsepyan не стоит править исходный вопрос так, что это меняет всю его суть.

Comment: @alexolut , а какая суть в  создании массива векторов, каждый из которых имеет только один элемент?  Просто очевидно, что это явная ошибка автора вопроса. И кстати, многие замечая это(я просто не заметил) вместо того, чтобы направить человеку к правильному решению, свой ответ строят на  том, что есть. Я это считаю недоброжелательностью

Comment: Изначально вектор был задуман именно массивом пар, это видно по самому вопросу.
    typedef std::pair<int, int> PairIntToInt; и PairIntToInt p;
то что касается кода выше, то код был изначально другим, я много чего от туда удалил да бы вставить код в стэк, что бы внимание было только на данном мне вопросе.

Comment: @Андрей Саламов, вы сами видите смысль  в массиве векторов?

Comment: @АндрейСаламов Т.е. вы понимаете, что по сути у вас что-то вроде двухмерного массива пар?

Comment: Не нужно вносить ответ в текст вопроса.

Comment: Я на стеке впервые по этому не гоните, скажем так, я учусь сейчас, и мне нужен был именно массив пар, я могу записывать и считывать значения с пары, и с вектора, но не с вектора пар.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно два цикла: Один по массиву, второй по парам внутри этого массива.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    std::cout << i << " = ";
    for (const auto &pair : vCt[i])
    {
        std::cout << pair.first << ":" << pair.second << "; ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает!

Comment: @АндрейСаламов как оно может работать, если `vCt` не является вектором векторов?

Comment: @alexolut Сначала это был массив векторов. AR Hovsepyan зачем-то изменил вопрос, сделав его просто вектором.

Comment: Жуть какая. Отозвал минус на ответе :)

Answer (score 2):

Через амперсанд & вы получаете адрес ячейки памяти, где хранится переменная. Через

```
VectorPairIntInt::iterator it = vCt.begin()
```

мы получаем указатель на первый элемент и далее проходим по вектору, пока не достигнем конца. Для каждого элемента мы можем получить поля first и second

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{

    int gg;

    typedef std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > VectorPairIntInt;
    VectorPairIntInt vCt;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        gg = rand() % 100;
        vCt.push_back(std::make_pair(i, gg));
    }

    for (VectorPairIntInt::iterator it = vCt.begin(); it != vCt.end(); it++) {
        std::cout << "First: " << it->first  << " Second: " << it->second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да с Амперсандом получаю ссылку, благодарю за ответ но случай с массивом.